# Flutter: how can I get text from decoration labelText so I can use it in a UI integration test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I would like to know if a solution similar to "driver.getText(find.byValueKey('key'))" I can use to get the labelText from decoration. I attached a SS with the Flutter Inspector showing the labelText [flutter inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgwNc.png)

Comment: You can share your code, not the screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the store the data("Parola")? Am I right? If so you can check shared preferences.

Here is the link I found on Medium:

https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127

Or you can use validator for a simple app:

https://medium.com/@michaeladesola1410/input-validation-flutter-dfe433caec5c

Comment: You could improve your answer adding the relevant code/explanation to your answer instead of just linking to external sources.

Comment: If there was a code snippet in the question instead of screenshot. I would be happy to do  that.